SQL BiGquery GA4 and INSERT INTO function to nested fields
I'm trying to insert data using the INSERT INTO statement, but I keep encountering an issue. Here is my query:
INSERT INTO mydataset (event_date, event_name, event_params)
VALUES 
('20221016', 'test', [STRUCT('key' AS key, STRUCT('NULL' AS string_value, NULL AS int_value, 12.34 AS float_value, NULL AS double_value))]);

I receive the following error message:
Cannot be inserted into column event_params, which has type ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRUCT<string_value STRING, int_value INT64, float_value FLOAT64, ...>>>

The problem seems to be with the value STRUCT part. How can I correctly format the value part before the STRUCT to match the expected data type?
Schema:

